# C++ Indexing structs

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, indexing, struct

I'm wondering if there is a way to index structs in order to run through the member variables in a for-loop. I'm asking repeatingly for stuff and get input via `cin>>`:

```
struct Fruits {
   string name;
   int weight, diameter, prize;
   string colour, smell, taste;
}apple;

cout << "Apple Name?"; cin >> apple.name;
cout << "Apple weight?"; cin >> apple.weight;
.
.
```

you get the idea. I want sth like

```
    vector<string> questions {"Apple Name?", "Apple weight?", ... };
    for (int j = 0; j < "StructureSize of Fruits"; j++)
    {
    cout << questions[j]; cin >> apple.j; //apple.j is the key point I want to know
    }
```

thank you very much!

Comment: Not really with different types, no. You can create an `operator[]` or `operator()` for your class, but that would be abuse for this use case. Just write a `Fruits readFruit();` function once and be done with it.

Comment: The names of the struct's fields are a compile time construct in C++. They are no longer available in the compiled program (other than in debugging info). So no, your problem --unfortunately-- cannot be solved like this.

Comment: @BaummitAugen the function may be sth I can try. the rest is beyond my horizon at current time :(

Comment: @dhke - ty anyway! I thought that must be a problem others already walked over too. but I couldn't find anything. guess now I know why :/

Comment: @CarolineSchuster The function is the best (i.e. most readable/maintainable) solution anyway. I just mentioned the operator stuff because I was afraid someone was going to suggest that. Very poor idea IMO.

Answer (score 2):

you can't.

Arrays access works on the following way.

```
int A[4];
A[0] = 5;
A[1] = 7;
A[3] = 8;
```

You know a int (in some archytectures) use 4 bytes. So, the first element of `A` is in the address `A`, the next element of A is in the address `A+4` what is equal to say `A+sizeof(int)`

When you do the first assignment `A[0]` the code is really something like `A+sizeof(int)*0`, in the next `A[1]` is something like `A+sizeof(int)*1` If you see, any adjacent space of the array sums 4 bytes ( or sizeof(int) ) and goes on. If you see, you know that A have integers inside of it and you know the pattern to access each element the general pattern in a for loop would be `A+sizeof(int)*j` in your struct you don't know what is inside, you can't do `A+sizeof(X)*j` becouse X isn't fixed, so, if you want to do that you must implement it yourself, but It would be a pain becouse you have mixed datatypes.

If your struct is fixed, the strings for the user should also be fixed, then why you try to print them from a loop?, The vector need to allocate and that use spaces and gpu, I think is better if you just print each option and then read the user input.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I hope my question wasn't too silly. I have no problem with typing the code, I just thought to you use an initialization loop for readability sake. I thought no real programmer would write all the stuff out and there must be a way to shorten this. but when this is ok and nobody would laugh about the length, then I am totally fine :)

Comment: @CarolineSchuster don't worry, isn't silly, what you want would be really nice, but C/C++ are typed languages and that have some pro/cons :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - don't understand the joke :(

Answer (score 2):

You can.

But not without overkilling it.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>

struct Fruit {
    std::string name;
    int weight, diameter, price;
    std::string colour, smell, taste;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Fruit,
    (std::string, name)
    (int, weight)
    (int, diameter)
    (int, price)
    (std::string, colour)
    (std::string, smell)
    (std::string, taste)
)

std::array<char const *const, 7> questions = {
    "Name ?",
    "Weight ?",
    "Diameter ?",
    "Price ?",
    "Colour ?",
    "Smell ?",
    "Taste ?"
};

int main() {
    Fruit apple;

    auto input = [i = std::size_t{0u}](auto &field) mutable {
        do {
        std::cout << questions[i] << ' ';
        } while(!(std::cin >> field));
        ++i;
    };
    boost::fusion::for_each(apple, std::ref(input));

    std::cout << "----------\n";

    auto output = [i = std::size_t{0u}](auto const &field) mutable {
        std::cout << questions[i] << ' ' << field << '\n';
        ++i;
    };
    boost::fusion::for_each(apple, std::ref(output));
}
```

I just learned that `boost::fusion::for_each` can't accept a mutable functor, hence the weird and a bit dangerous use of `std::ref()`... It's a shame, really.

Output :

```
Name ? Apple
Weight ? 150
Diameter ? 8
Price ? 1
Colour ? red
Smell ? good    
Taste ? sweet
----------
Name ? Apple
Weight ? 150
Diameter ? 8
Price ? 1
Colour ? red
Smell ? good
Taste ? sweet
```

Comment: wow.. you mean "But not without overkilling **me**." .. lol. that works? I nearly understand the half. _boost_, _std::ref_, _mutable_ - things I haven't heard of yet. will need some days to understand your code :( - but for now, ty!

Comment: @CarolineSchuster when you want to kill a fly, of a flyswatter and a shotgun, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is often the orbital strike. But it *does* work :p

Answer (score 1):

```
enum FruitValueProperty { weight=0, diameter, prize, lastValueProperty };
enum FruitStringProperty { name=0, colour, smell, taste, lastStringProperty };

struct Fruit {
    int ValueProperty[3];
    string StringProperty[4];

    int Weight() { return ValueProperty[weight]; }
    int Diameter() { return ValueProperty[diameter]; }
    int Prize() { return ValueProperty[prize]; }

    string Name() { return StringProperty[name]; }
    string Colour() { return StringProperty[colour]; }
    string Smell() { return StringProperty[smell]; }
    string Taste () { return StringProperty[taste ]; }
};

Fruit fruit;
vector<string> questions {"Fruit weight?", ... "Fruit name?", ... };

for (int i=0; i<lastValueProperty; i++) {
    cout << questions[j];
    cin >> fruit.ValueProperty[i];
}

for (int j=0; i<lastStringProperty; i++) {
    cout << questions[lastValueProperty+j];
    cin >> fruit.StringProperty[j];
}

int dim = fruit.Diameter();
string sm = fruit.Smell();
```

If you used enums for the string properties (limiting the scope of what the values could be i.e an enum for names, enum for colors etc) then you could get your result by condensing the two loops down to one.
Alternatively you could have set property for the int values that takes a string and parses it to int and go that route but I honestly thing the above is the simplest and **clearest** means to ***almost*** achieve what you want.

Comment: thank you! seems well comprehensible. do you think my question would be easier without the _strings_? if the struct only contained _ints_?

Comment: You could replace each string with an enum E.g enum Color { Blue, Red ... } and then store enum value in single int ValueProperty array.  Your get accessor functions could convert the enum to string i.e you could keep string Name() - but now it would have to do enum to string conversion.  You could then work with a single loop.  Up to you which choice is preferable.

Comment: Your user input for the question "What color" is going to be a string.  I guess the real question is to what extent do you want to parse, validate and coerse this to a fix value (E.g Blue) or allow free text (E.g Lightish green).  For the former do as suggested in above comment for the later do as per original answer.

Comment: But, If you're going to do something like this, and using C++, we could use maps?

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on the matter using just vanilla c++ and evil macros and casts. Still definitely overkill though.

The basic plan is to provide an  operator[] to return a variant-type proxy class which in turn handles the io streams.

This interface allows you the ability to expose the class members as you choose and in the order you want.

In order not to repeat myself and to avoid having the burden of keeping things in sync I declare the fields I want in a separate header and include the header twice but changing the macro between includes. If I now add a new field or remove one then I only have to change one place.

**fruit_fields.h**

```
//NO Header Guards desired since we want to include multiple times

DECLARE_FIELD(std::string,  Fruit, name)
DECLARE_FIELD(int,          Fruit, weight)
DECLARE_FIELD(int,          Fruit, diameter)
DECLARE_FIELD(int,          Fruit, prize)
DECLARE_FIELD(std::string,  Fruit, colour)
DECLARE_FIELD(std::string,  Fruit, smell)
DECLARE_FIELD(std::string,  Fruit, taste)
```

**Utility Classes**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <typeinfo>


//TypeId info
namespace FieldType
{
    static const size_t String = typeid(std::string).hash_code();
    static const size_t Integer = typeid(int).hash_code();
};


/*
Field Proxy is a simple variant class
If you want to support more field types then more code is needed
*/
class FieldProxy
{

public:
    FieldProxy(int* value)
        : m_typeHash( typeid(int).hash_code() )
        , m_intValue(value)
    {}

    FieldProxy(std::string* value)
        : m_typeHash(typeid(std::string).hash_code())
        , m_stringValue(value)
    {}

    operator int() const
    {
        assert(m_typeHash == typeid(int).hash_code());
        return *m_intValue;
    }

    operator std::string() const
    {
        assert(m_typeHash == typeid(std::string).hash_code());
        return *m_stringValue;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const FieldProxy& field);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& os, FieldProxy& field);


private:
    size_t m_typeHash;
    union
    {
        int* m_intValue;
        std::string* m_stringValue;
    };

};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const FieldProxy& field)
{
    if (field.m_typeHash == FieldType::Integer)
    {
        os << *(field.m_intValue);
    }
    else if (field.m_typeHash == FieldType::String)
    {
        os << *(field.m_stringValue);
    }

    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, FieldProxy& field)
{

    if (field.m_typeHash == FieldType::Integer)
    {
        is >> *(field.m_intValue);
    }
    else if (field.m_typeHash == FieldType::String)
    {
        is >> *(field.m_stringValue);
    }       

    return is;
}

//data to obtain pointer to given field
struct FieldInfo
{
    size_t fieldType;
    size_t offset;
};
```

**Fruit Class**

```
//The struct we actually care about
struct Fruit
{
public:

    static size_t getNumberFields() 
    {
        return m_numberFields;
    }

    FieldProxy operator[](size_t index);

private:
//First include just declares the class members as you might expect
// string name;
// int    weight; etc

#define DECLARE_FIELD(t, c, f) t f;
#include "fruit_fields.h"
#undef DECLARE_FIELD


    static FieldInfo m_fields[];
    static const size_t m_numberFields;

};

//Work out where the fields are positioned in the class
FieldInfo Fruit::m_fields[] =
{
   //second time around - define the macro to generate the data
   //needed to build the FieldProxy

#define DECLARE_FIELD( t, c, f) {typeid(t).hash_code(), offsetof(c,f)},
#include "fruit_fields.h"
#undef DECLARE_FIELD
};

//calculate how many fields there are
const size_t Fruit::m_numberFields = sizeof(Fruit::m_fields) / sizeof(Fruit::m_fields[0]);

//Index to a FieldInfo object and use it to create a FieldProxy variant
FieldProxy Fruit::operator[](size_t index)
{
    assert(index < m_numberFields);

    auto& fieldInfo = m_fields[index];

    if (fieldInfo.fieldType == FieldType::Integer)
    {
        return FieldProxy(reinterpret_cast<int*> (reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + fieldInfo.offset));
    }
    else if (fieldInfo.fieldType == FieldType::String)
    {
        return FieldProxy(reinterpret_cast<std::string*> (reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + fieldInfo.offset));
    }
    else
    {
        assert(false);
        return FieldProxy((int*)nullptr);
    }
}
```

**Main**
You can now index in to the fruit class quite simply:

```
int main() 
{
    Fruit apple;

    std::array<std::string, 7> questions = {
        "Name ?",
        "Weight ?",
        "Diameter ?",
        "Price ?",
        "Colour ?",
        "Smell ?",
        "Taste ?"
    };

    assert(questions.size() == Fruit::getNumberFields());

    for (size_t index = 0; index < Fruit::getNumberFields(); ++index)
    {
        bool succeeded = false;
        do {
            std::cout << questions[index] << ' ';
            if (!(std::cin >> apple[index]))
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
            }
            else
            {
                succeeded = true;
            }
        } while (!succeeded);
    }

    std::cout << "----------" << std::endl;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < Fruit::getNumberFields(); ++index)
    {
        std::cout << questions[index] << ' ' << apple[index] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh dear, definitively overkill :o .. I didn't think it would be that difficult. even though I have 20 member variables in the struct that I'm going to ask, it might be better just to type all the `cin>>` per hand. I was afraid it is sth that a real programmer would laugh at me, but seems fine here.

Answer (score 0):

OK it is long since the thread was started.

For indexing a Struct with values of same type I have written this code:

```
struct DataValues
{
    int Value1;
    int Value2;
    int Value3;
    int Value4;
    int Value5;
    int Value6;
    int Value7;
    int Value8;

    // the operator
    // return the reference to make it settable.
    int& operator[](int n) 
    {
        // the idea, get the pointer of the first element
        // and treat it as an array
        return (&Value1)[n];
    }
};
```

usage:

```
int main()
{
    DataValues values;

    values.Value4 = 6;
    values[1] = 3;
    values[0] = sizeof(DataValues);

    return 0;
}
```

The downside is that you have to check the input parameter to avoid accessing memory which  does not belong to the struct.

Chears